# Task manager: Hide when minimized without GUI

Tags: windows, command-line, task-manager, command-line-arguments

When you launch `taskmgr.exe`, there is an option "Hide When Minimized" (under Options menu).

I am looking for how to run it with that option without using GUI in the task manager itself.

That is, a command line parameter would be perfect. A registry "hack" would be OK as well (not so good, though).

I use Windows 7, but I believe the Windows version is not very significant here.

Comment: Taskmagaer saves the "Hide when minimized" option persistently. Therefore you just have to make a shortcut to taskmgr.exe and set the option "Run Minimized".

Comment: Robert, I know. But it is a part of script which should "just work" out of the box, even for people who run it for the first time.

Comment: Then use Process Monitor and filter for registry and taskmgr.exe. Then you will see where the "Hide when Minized" option is stored in the registy so that you can set this option in your script.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 8.1 and above, you can save the Task Manager registry settings to a .reg file and then apply it to clean Windows installs using a batch file.

#### Step 1

[image]

In regedit, navigate to the following registry key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\TaskManager
```

#### Step 2

[image]

Right-click on the TaskManager key in the pane on the left side and press Export. Save as TaskManagerSettings.reg

#### Step 3 **[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563975/how-to-make-a-batch-file-execute-a-reg-file)**

[image]
Create a .bat file in the same directory with the following

```
 @echo off
 rem  set __COMPAT_LAYER=RunAsInvoker  
 REGEDIT.EXE  /S  "%~dp0\TaskManagerSettings.reg"
 pause
```

Comment: I have upvoted, but it should be noted that it will affect all settings of Task Manager, not just "hide when minimized".